# JPA: Why is it bad to store Serialized form of a property?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In Java Persistence with Hibernate, section 5.1 the author recommended:

> if the type of the property is java.io.Serializable, its value is
>   stored in its serialized form. This typically isn’t what you want, and
>   you should always map Java classes instead of storing a heap of bytes
>   in the database. Imagine maintaining a database with this binary
>   information when the application is gone in a few years.

Can someone please elaborate on this?

Is it not the case that if the type of a property is `java.io.Serializable` then all its attributes/fields are serializable and this is in fact **required** for a property to persisted?

Answer (score 1):

From a database perspective, this is unstructured data, stored as a BLOB (byte large object) or CLOB (character large object)...it's inefficient to store (why not just store on a file system or in a content management system), most databases have special (re: obnoxious) APIs to deal with them, you can't do any query off of them, so it's just bad all the way around.

Even though from your perspective it's a class with a structure, natively the database is not going to be able to deal with it as such unless you have various plugins, addons, OO database, etc., so it's just a bunch of bytes.